# Can you target x86 with mysql server and connector c++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to use MySQL with a visual studio using SFML. This library needs to be used with x86 as the active platform solution. However, the MySQL server and connector c++ uses an x64 architecture and doesn't work when the active platform solution is set to x86.

Is there a way to get the server and connector to work with x86? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you build the source for mysql connector as a 32 bit program?

Comment: Why do people still bother with x86 in 2021? Are there even machines left with less than 4 GB of memory? x86 is history... Anyway, the server can remain x64, but you need a x86 library. It can be installed in addition to x64.

Comment: 1st (or 3rd) package here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: im not very knowledgeable about the subject was just looking for advice on how to solve the situation. I tried downloading the 32-bit version of the server and it got rid of the previous error but now says:                                           
         Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1112 module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' zombie C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Final Year Project\Achievement_Libary\Achievemnt\2020-year-4-fyp-MadMitten\zombie\sfml-window-d.lib(sfml-window-d-2.dll) 1

Comment: @Madmitten All of your libraries (and DLLs) need to be x64 or x86 not just some of them. It __looks like__ `sfml` is also x64 and needs to be replaced with a x86 version.

Comment: i don't think SFML has a 86 version is their a way to get it to work with either 32 or 64?

Comment: @Madmitten Yes it does https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/

Comment: Which one should i be using as I've tried using the 32 bit version and set the active platform to x64 and the library cant seem to detect the header file I'm trying to access. But if I set it back to x86 it works